# What is the best way to log the request of downloading file

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, download

I used an ashx handler to send requested file to user, as the below code:

```
// Here . Log the time and IP of the whom request the file
context.Response.ClearContent();
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=AppName.apk");
context.Response.TransmitFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/AppName.apk"));
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.End();
```

before, sending file I logged the user request.
but I encounter an issue, some times, the count of log for one request is more than once, and I don't know why this happened, and how could be avoid it?
also, what is the best solution for logging the requests which could be specified the count of request?

Comment: Doesn't the web server has this functionality already?

Comment: I don't know, Do you know?